Domains not showing on cpanel
I migrate an cpanel from another server, but the problem is all domain not showing in cpanel domain list, but when go to email section and create new email showing all domains, How to fix it please help anyone.
I migrate this cpanel from another server, I also see all the domains is working on email. Even emails also working received and send just not showing in Domain section and only showing cpanel default page when open domain in browser.
Please help to fix this.
